# Better jmeter report

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

Currently I use jmeter aggregate report or summary report for submitting reports. But they expect something extra.. How can I give. Is there any plugins for getting server resources usage when testing load.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reporting: since JMeter 3.0 there is a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which can be generated during the test run. It contains exhaustive overview information. If you need to find out the reason of the bottleneck or memory leak or whatever you can consider extra [Graphs](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project.
2. The same JMeter Plugins project provides [PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) - client-server application which is able to collect over 70 different metrics and plot them via JMeter Listener. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for detailed setup and usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few plug-ins available that can help you analyze the results better. You can refer to https://jmeter-plugins.org/ for the same.

Most popularly used ones are:

1. Response Times Over Time
2. Response Times Percentiles
3. Transactions per Second
4. Response Latencies Over Time

In case of server usage you can use following that comes with JMeter plug-ins

PerfMon Metrics Collector and Server Agent or

In case of Unix based system use sar command that comes with sysstat package or VMstat. In case of windows based system use Perfmon to capture the system utilization data while the test is running and then use Ksar to plot graphs with the data collected using sar. https://sourceforge.net/projects/ksar/

If you have collected data using Perfmon then plot the graphs using PAL. https://pal.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would suggest using Grafana. It shows realtime results. And the best thing is, it can be configured according to the need.

Now, the thing is how to use it? Using it is not that tough.

If you're using a Mac or Linux (Any Flavour) things become easy. If you're using Windows, I would suggest using a virtual machine. The reason behind that is windows block traffic after some requests. And that causes a lot of pain in the head.

In my case, I used a virtual machine to setup ubuntu inside it and then configured Grafana.

For working with Grafana, you need to have these two things installed.

1. Grafana Itself
2. Influx Db for the backend

Links for both here below:
https://grafana.com/grafana/download?platform=linux
https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/

Once installed and setup,

You need to use Backen Listener to push results o Graphite Client (Installed along with Influx DB Automatically).

I know it is a bit confusing but once you understand the thing, you and your client will love the detailed reports.

Remeber, Grafana is all about configuration.

Let me know if you have any confusion regarf=ding this.

Happy to help. :)